# Could Rick Sanchez C-137 be prosecuted for impersonating his alternative self?

Tags: plot-explanation, rick-and-morty

[In the episode "Rick Potion #9"](http://rickandmorty.wikia.com/wiki/Rick_Potion), an alternative Rick managed to save the world from the love potion but died soon afterwards due to a freak accident.

Rick and Morty C-147 had come in and take their place. The episode ends with Rick and Morty, burying their dead bodies in the backyard.

Now the next bit requires a bit of imagination; **If** a cop or a government official or etc, found out Rick is in fact not the "**real**" Rick Sanchez and lets imagine that Rick is taken to court (even though its likely he would just decline and end up killing a bunch of people) and or Gerry decides to take Rick to court (because Gerry naturally hates Rick) could he be charged on the grounds of impersonation?

According to ["The Legal Dictionary"](https://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Impersonation); The (crime) impersonation is:

> The crime of pretending to be another individual **in order to deceive others** and gain some **advantage**.

Rick is impersonating his alternative self to take advantage of their dimension because their original one got destroyed and he deceives his own family in order to live their pretending to be the "original" Rick and Morty.

Now the difficult bit is, could Rick be charged with impersonating his alternative self? or is it out of the jurisdiction or power of the law to determine such things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're talking about a local (to that reality) law court, then I'm pretty sure that Rick & Morty from C-147 are virtually identical to their counterparts, same looks, fingerprints, DNA, etc. The only difference is they couldn't figure out how to save the world, while their local counterparts could, but blew themselves up too. So no local authority figures would be able to tell them apart in the first place.

Even if the locals *could* tell that they're alternate reality replacements, that's a virtually insane idea and the prosecuting attorney or officer would likely appear insane & be locked up. And there's no law against trading places with yourself from an alternate reality.

And, if your legal definition is correct, there's no real advantage to deceiving others in this way, in fact they could be helping others by thinking Rick & Morty are still alive & well.

---

But, if you're talking about a court of Ricks, in the [Citadel of Ricks](http://rickandmorty.wikia.com/wiki/Citadel_of_Ricks), they *would* be able to tell that Rick & Morty from C-147 are in the "wrong" reality, but I'm sure they shouldn't have any laws against it, many other Ricks probably did the same thing. And they're probably the last court that would listen to Jerry either.

---

But, being that there could be *infinite* realities where virtually anything could happen, it's conceivable that somewhere there *is* a court in some weird reality that *would* try prosecuting Rick & Morty in such a case, and Rick & Morty would probably lose too... but I'd expect to see sharks jumping all over the place in that reality.

Comment: should add that in Season 3 Rick "repaired" his relations with the US by making it seem that he left and another Rick was assigned to take his place. so at the very least the US President is aware that Rick could be swapped around

Comment: @Memor-X I'm not caught up on season 3 yet, so *I'm not looking, lalalalala!* ;-)

Comment: A more relevant distinction here is that it's unlikely that an Earth court could convict Rick even if Rick himself testified to the events. As long as he didn't kill the old Rick, he did not actually break any law, as there is no law concerning interdimensional identities.